# OpenVAS & greenbone kills rsync

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, rsync, openvas

I am trying to install OpenVAS9 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (clean installation).

**Problem:**
After the `sudo apt install openvas9` I need to sync all the stuff from openvas (see [Install Guide](http://olivermarshall.net/how-to-install-openvas-9-on-ubuntu-16/) or the STDOUT during openvas installation).
To sync the data I have to call:
`sudo greenbone-nvt-sync`
`sudo greenbone-scapdata-sync`
`sudo greenbone-certdata-sync`

I have set the RSYNC_PROXY and http/https proxy variables because we are using a proxy in our network.

When running `greenbone-nvt-sync` the first time, anything works fine. But calling `greenbone-scapdata-sync` after fails. Even if I try to call `greenbone-nvt-sync` two times in a row, the second call fails.

*The Error Message:*

```
bad response from proxy -- HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

My question:
Does I have to mind something? Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, but according to the log

```
bad response from proxy -- HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

I guess, your proxy forbids certain ports that rsync relies on.